# Angular nativeElement offsetTop alway 0

Tags: javascript, angular

Im working in a menu where the current section is gonna be select it on scroll, but when i try to get the offsetTop of the elements i get alway 0 for some reason, on the parentElement a get value for offsetTop but in this case does not work for me using the offsetTop of the parentElement because i have many childElements inside with different offsetTop.

**Template**

```
    <div nxCol="12,12,8" *ngIf="selectedPlan && selectedPlan?.id != quotePlan.id && !loading">
        <!-- Limits -->
        <h5 class="nx-margin-y-0" translate [id]="LIMITS_AND_PRICING_SECTION_ID" #limitPricing> page.service-detail.available-plan.menu.limit-pricing </h5>
        <mat-list class="mat-list-padding-none">
            <mat-list-item><strong translate>global.label.limits</strong></mat-list-item>
            <mat-divider></mat-divider>
            <mp-service-plan-limit-display [limits]="selectedPlan?.limits"></mp-service-plan-limit-display>
        </mat-list>

        <mat-list class="nx-margin-top-m mat-list-padding-none">
            <mat-list-item><strong translate>page.service-detail.pricing</strong></mat-list-item>
            <mat-divider></mat-divider>
            <mp-service-plan-price-display
                [prices]="selectedPlan?.prices"
                [planId]="selectedPlan?.id"
                [availablePlans]="true"
            ></mp-service-plan-price-display>
        </mat-list>
        <!-- /Limits -->

        <!-- Documentation -->
        <ng-container *ngIf="planSpecDocuments.length > 0">
            <h5 class="nx-margin-top-3xl nx-margin-bottom-2xs" translate [id]="DOCUMENTATION_SECTION_ID" #documentation>
                page.service-detail.available-plan.menu.documentation
            </h5>
            <p class="nx-margin-0">Details how to embed the Service into your application.</p>
            <mat-list class="mat-list-padding-none mat-file-list">
                <ng-container *ngFor="let specDocument of planSpecDocuments">
                    <mat-list-item>
                        <ng-container *ngIf="(partnerId$ | async)?.length && !isPreview; else documentSpecDisabledTpl">
                            <a [href]="specDocument.specDocumentUrl | async" [download]="specDocument.name" class="file-links file-link-active">
                                <span class="icon-document mpt-icon"></span>{{ specDocument.name }}
                            </a>
                        </ng-container>
                        <ng-template #documentSpecDisabledTpl>
                            <span class="file-links">
                                <span class="icon-document mpt-icon"></span>
                                {{ specDocument.name }}
                            </span>
                        </ng-template>
                    </mat-list-item>
                </ng-container>
            </mat-list>
        </ng-container>
        <!-- /Documentation -->
    </div>
```

**Component**

```
@ViewChild('limitPricing') limitPricing!: ElementRef;
@ViewChild('documentation') documentation!: ElementRef;
@ViewChild('swaggerSpec') swaggerSpec!: ElementRef;

    timer(500).subscribe(() => {
        console.dir(this.limitPricing?.nativeElement);
        this.limitPricingOffset = this.limitPricing?.nativeElement.offsetTop - 100; // offsetTop here is always zero
        this.documentationOffset = this.documentation?.nativeElement.offsetTop - 100;
        this.swaggerSpecOffset = this.swaggerSpec?.nativeElement.offsetTop - 100;
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare the element in the constructor, as **`private _element: ElementRef) { ...}`**

```
this._element.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect().top
```